# AngularJS - Credit Card Expiration date format to validate form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date

I am learning AngularJS, and I am making a credit card validator. 
I have implemented the Luhn Algorithm in a custom filter and it works perfectly. However, in order to validate the form I want also the expiration date to be valid, ie to fulfill these conditions:
- 08/16
- 02/2015
- 0518
- the date shall not be expired (obviously)

So since I found out there was already date filter in Angular, I tried to create one. To me it seems logical, but it does not work at all. Here's the code:

```
/**
* validate-expiry-date Module
*
* Validates the date format and that the date is not in the past
*/
angular.module('validate-expiry-date', []).filter('validDate', [function () {
  return function (date) {

    var actualDate = new Date();
    var m,y,d;

    if (/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/.test(date)) {
        m = date.substring(0, 2);
        y = 20 + date.slice(-2);
        d = new Date(y,m);
        return(actualDate > d);
    }if (/^\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(date)) {
        m = date.substring(0, 2);
        y = date.slice(-4);
        d = new Date(y,m);
        return(actualDate > d);
    }else if (/^\d{4}$/.test(date)) {
        m = date.substring(0, 2);
        y = 20 + date.slice(-2);
        d = new Date(y,m);
        return(actualDate > d);
    };
  }
}])
```

Anyone could explain me what's going on ?
Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter function works *conceptually*  (although your interpretation of months is off by one, look up docs on the `Date` constructor). Your problem is fitting it into what angular expects.

Rather than receiving a single date string, as you have assumed here, you actually get the full array which needs filtering. And rather than returning true/false, you need to return the modified (filtered) array.

However, the function you wrote fits beautifully with `Array.prototype.filter`, so it works in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fR7w1JSFrl0mVc2xpJMM?p=preview) I fixed up.

Here's the relevant changes:

```
function filterSingleDate(date) {
    var actualDate = new Date();
    var m,y,d;

    if (/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/.test(date)) {
        m = date.substring(0, 2) - 1;
        y = 20 + date.slice(-2);
        d = new Date(y,m);
    } else if (/^\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(date)) {
        m = date.substring(0, 2) - 1;
        y = date.slice(-4);
        d = new Date(y,m);
    } else if (/^\d{4}$/.test(date)) {
        m = date.substring(0, 2) - 1;
        y = 20 + date.slice(-2);
        d = new Date(y,m);
    }

    return actualDate > d;
}

var FilterModule = angular.module('FilterModule', []).filter('validDate', [function () {
  return function (dateList) {
    return dateList.filter(filterSingleDate);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks! so basically I had the logic, I just didn't use Angular properly: I messed up validation with filtering. Thanks a lot !